# How do I drill down to specific data in my LINQ query result?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to drill down into a particular item in my data and output the list of results to the output window.  My query result looks like this

```
private IEnumerable<DataRow> _data;

var query = from data in this._data
        group data by data.Field<string>("Form Name") into groups //same as Form ID
        select new 
        {
            formName = groups.Key,
            items = from d in groups
                     group d by d.Field<string>("Item Name") into grps
                     let name = grps.Key
                     let documentIDGroups = grps.GroupBy(t => t.Field<string>("Document ID"))
                     let documentIDGroupsCount = documentIDGroups.Count()

                     let distinctDocumentValueCount = from data in documentIDGroups
                                                 select new
                                                 { 
                                                     docID = data.Key,
                                                     distinctDocValueCount = data.Where(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Field<string>("Document Value").Trim()) == false).Select(t => t.Field<string>("Document Value")).Distinct().Count()
                                                 }


                     let sum = distinctDocumentValueCount.Sum(t => t.distinctDocValueCount)

                     let distinctItemsNames = from data in grps
                                              select data.Field<string>("Item Name").Distinct().Count()

                     let count = distinctItemsNames.Count()

                     select new 
                     {
                         itemName = name,

                         documentIDGroups,
                         documentIDGroupsCount,

                         averageChoices = Math.Round(((decimal)sum / documentIDGroupsCount), 2),

                         distinctDocumentValueCount,

                         sum

                     }
        };
```

So on that query result I want to drill down into a particular form name, and from there get a particular Item Name and so on

so the first step is to get the grouping of items and I have

```
var items = from d in query where d.formName == "someName" select d.items;
```

but I don't know how to isolate the items by a particular string.
I want to do the following

```
var item = from d in items where d.itemName == "anItemName" select d;
```

But I don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .FirstOrDefault extension if you expect a single item to be returned from your query. SO:

```
var item = (from d in items where d.itemName == "anItemName" select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ok thanks that fixes my first query,  var form = (from d in query where d.formName == "someName" select d).FirstOrDefault(), how can I isolate the items by item name in the next wuery?;

Comment: General note: If you expect *exactly* 1 item, and getting more than one, or `0` would be an error, you should use `.First` instead of `.FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @erotavlas I'm not sure exactly what you mean by isolate them by name. Do you want to select only the name? Do you want all items with the same name?

Comment: @BradleyUffner .Single is correct in that case, not .First.